# The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values ERROR

Tags: django, nginx, cors

I have an app with react frontend and django backend. I have a problem, when the frontend wants to get a file from the backend, an error appears

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://api.(site name).com/documents/15/' (redirected from 'http://api.(site name).com/documents/15') from origin 'http://www.(site name).com' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://www.sitename.com, *', but only one is allowed.`

my nginx.conf on my server

```
server {

    server_name api.sitename.com;

    listen 80;

    server_tokens off;
    client_max_body_size 10m;
    root /var/html/;

#    location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
#        root /var/www/certbot;
#    }

    location / {
      if ($request_method = 'POST') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;
     }
     if ($request_method = 'GET') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;
     }

      if ($request_method = OPTIONS ) {
        add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" '*' always;
        add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, POST, OPTIONS, HEAD";
        add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept";
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        return 204;
    }
        # proxy_set_header Host $host;
        # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        # proxy_pass http://backend:8000;
    }


    location /media/ {
        autoindex on;
    }

    location /docs/ {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        try_files $uri $uri/redoc.html;
    }

    location /static/rest_framework/ {
        autoindex on;
    }

    location /static/admin/ {
         autoindex on;
    }
  

    location /admin/ {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_pass http://backend:8000/admin/;
    }

    
      # error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
      # location = /50x.html {
      #   root   /var/html/frontend/;
      # }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name sitename.com www.sitename.com;
    

    server_tokens off;
    client_max_body_size 10m;
    root /var/html/;
  
#    location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
#        root /var/www/certbot;
#}

    location / {
    #     if ($request_method ~* "(GET|POST)") {
    #       add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" '*' always;
    # }

    #     if ($request_method = OPTIONS ) {
    #       add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  *;
    #       add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, POST, OPTIONS, HEAD";
    #       add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept";
    #       return 200;
    # }
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
      }
}
```

If i delete this `add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;`
I recieve
Access to fetch at api. ....... .com  from origin 'http://www............com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I turned off CORS on Django but when it was turned on the error was the same

Comment: You must have configured CORS elsewhere than in your NGINX configuration... You should configure CORS in at most one place or you're bound to run into this kind of problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `*` from CORS header because it has to be more specific, so something like:

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://www.sitename.com' always;
```

Another possible problem is your CORS header at the API level, meaning if your API also has CORS headers that can override or conflict with the headers at the NGINX proxy level.

For example, one time I was setting CORS headers both in NGINX and ExpressJS and that caused unexpected errors.

Hope it helps.